# Recommended way to process different payload types in Asp.Net WebHooks for same sender

Tags: asp.net-webhooks

I'm setting up an Asp.Net WebHook receiver for an internal webhook from a different server in the same application. I'm therefore using the built-in CustomWebHookReceiver. The webhook needs to send several different payload types as JSON, which need to be de-serialized into different strong types by the receiver and be processed differently.

Since the only difference between invocations of the webhook are the payload, a single webhook receiver will be configured for a single id, following the pattern of placing the shared secret in the web.config AppSetting as:

```
MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_<receiver>
```

What is the best way to implement different webhook handling behavior for the different payload types. Creating separate receivers or separate ids for the different payload types does not seem appropriate, since the security models are identical and writing a new receiver seems like overkill.

Creating different handlers seems like the right direction, but built-in settings appear to only allow a handler to specify the receiver and the priority. This leaves the option of inspecting the payload inside the handler's ExecuteAsync method and deciding how to process the message.

Is this correct, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom, you can use the {id} part of the URI to receive as many WebHooks using the same handler and then differentiate them based on the {id}. You can find more details about how to set this up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers).

Hope this helps!

Henrik